# Chart.js v2 - hiding grid lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I am using Chart.js v2 to draw a simple line chart. Everything looks fine, except there are grid lines that I don't want:

[image: Grid Lines I don't want]

The documentation for Line Chart is here: https://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/#line-chart, but I can't find anything about hiding those "Grid Lines".

How can I remove the grid lines?

Answer (score 463, accepted):

I found a solution that works for hiding the grid lines in a Line chart.

Set the `gridLines` color to be the same as the div's background color.

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            }   
        }]
    }
}
```

or use

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }   
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually setting the gridLines color to a `0 opacity` black (a transparent color). So this should work regardless of the div's background color.

Comment: Or use display:false, instead of "color"

Comment: I wanted to keep the scale but lose the gridlines on the back of the chart so this answer did not work for me.

Comment: While this first answer may get to the desired picture, it is a bit of a hack. The second solution, that actually sets the gridLines display property to false, seems to be more correct.

Comment: This is also removing lines of x axis(single line) and y axis(single line). But i only wanted to remove lines on the graph. So drawOnChartArea: false is doing the right thing.

Comment: gridLines is now grid in ChartJS 3

Answer (score 211):

From version 3.x, onwards use this syntax.
Refer to chart.js migration guide: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html

```
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false
    }
  },
  y: {
    grid: {
      display: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be voted higher. I was wondering why none of the answers above were working!

Comment: Indeed august 2021, the accepted answers didn't work anymore, but this one did.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I was wondering why other solutions are throwing error "Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes" it because of version. Chart.js 3+ options are different than that of older version.

Comment: yes, other solutions no longer work but this does, should be accepted answer

Comment: This code can also be used as a short alternative. hides both x and y coordinate lines: 
```Chart.defaults.scale.grid.display = false;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `options: { scales: { ... } }`

Answer (score 97):

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer allowed me to keep the scale but not draw the gridlines on the chart.

Comment: I think this is rather the better answer.

Comment: Good answer. This is cleaner though: `Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false;`

Comment: @Kalimah: the above (in options) code worked for me. The “cleaner” solution does not work for me with “chartjs-chart-error-bars” plugin

Answer (score 28):

If you want them gone by default, you can set:

```
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display = false;
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to hide gridlines but want to show yAxes, you can set:

```
yAxes: [{...
         gridLines: {
                        drawBorder: true,
                        display: false
                    }
       }]
```

Answer (score 11):

The code below removes remove grid lines from chart area only not the ones in x&y axis labels

```
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer since this is not change anything out the draw area, Thanks Ahmed

Answer (score 9):

OK, nevermind.. I found the trick:

```
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

In chartjs 3 there is a little difference in accessing this configuration. The name of the property is not `gridLines`, but `grid`, as it is shown in the official documentation:

> `options.gridLines` was renamed to `options.grid`

Source:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#ticks

Here is how it looks:

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Hristo, next time, could you please point to the documentation of the library to help guide the person asking the question. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to the official documentation:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

Below code changes would hide the gridLines:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }   
    }]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Updated code for ChartJs, version = 4.3.0

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          grid:{
              display:false
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

An update for ChartJS 3:

```
  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },

      y: {
        grid: {
          // display: false,
          color: 'rgba(217,143,7,0.1)',
        },
      },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this did it for me on my react project

```js
scales: {
    xAxis:{
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
    
}
```

i hope this helps