# How to hide the grid lines of react chart js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to hide gridlines of react-chartjs-2 line chart. I have tried with the below code. But not working.

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            drawTicks: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }],
}
```

Sandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-tm7hj

Comment: You can try this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54472698/11834630]

Comment: @souravsatyam Still not working.

Comment: Hide it by default Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display = false;  It is working in Sanbox. Though this isn't a solution.