# Hide grids in Bar Graph

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    BarElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    BarElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
);



const options = {
    responsive: true,
    elements: {
        bar: {
            borderWidth: 2,
        },
    },
    plugins: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                grid: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            y: {
                grid: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            // text: 'Top Application Accessed',
        },
    },
};

const labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d0", "d", "e", "t"];
const v = [8, 10, 15, 2, 4, 11, 17]

const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Total no of errors",
            data: v,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }
    ],
};

export default function App() {
    return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

In the above code All the code inside scales is not having any effect.
I want to hide grids from my chart.

I want to also add some features to my chart but anything I add to this code having no effect in the results.

Instead of full grids I want dotted grid only parallel to x axis.
I also want to add different colors to all the bars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js v2 - hiding grid lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676263/chart-js-v2-hiding-grid-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have putted your scale condif in the plugins section of the options object. This is incorrect, you need to place the scales section in the root of the options object. Then it will work fine.

So instead of `options.plugins.scales.x` and `options.plugins.scales.y` you will get: `options.scales.x` and `options.scales.y`

Comment: is there any way to add dotted lines to it

Comment: you need to set dash in `options.scales[scaleId].border` to `[2,2]` or any other 2 numbers depending on how you want it to look

Comment: thanku so much.. Is there any proper documentation where I can find all these stuff?

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/